# How to call controller function from html tag which is input to other div

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm following line which makes the call to controller function i.e demoMethod.

```
document.getElementById("FileDisplay").innerHTML += "<span onclick=\"$(#control).demoMethod()\"></span>"+children[i]+"</br>";`
```

and demoMethod is declared inside the controller

```
$scope.demoMethod = function(){
        console.log("it works");
     }
```

and FileDisplay is the id of div in HTML file, how can I call this method inside from span element..?

Thank you

Comment: Please provide more details and maybe complete code.

Comment: [Avoid using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15012542/8495123).

Answer (score 3):

Don't call your function with jQuery.

Use AngularJS `ng-click`, it's simpler:

```
<span ng-click="demoMethod()"></span>
```